# simple preg_replace rule that I can't get to work

Tags: preg-replace

Can't understand how to do this preg_replace, haven't tried as don't know what to try on it, too hard to understand..

```
index-D.html where d is a digit from 0-99999
```

how to replace occurrences of that string, `index-D.html` to empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) is pretty clear and provides examples as well:

```
$string = "index-D.html where d is a digit from 0-99999";
$pattern = "index-D.html";
$new_string = preg_replace($pattern, "", $string);
```